# How to prevent endless loop when using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#

C# question.

I have a class which is used for multiple instances of objects. These contain properties, and I use INotifyPropertChanged to notify multiple listener classes that a property has changed. Say a network manager class, which sets the property value in the object.

The problem is, the object triggers INotifyPropertyChanged, which the network manager class then picks up as a change, so it changes the property again. Endless loop.

Most examples compare the value, and stop the loop when the values match. Unfortunately, this means each listener class needs a copy of the values of all the objects, just for comparison.

My idea so far is I could abandon using properties altogether, and set all values with a method, e.g. SetPropertyA(Object Sender, String value) which will include the sender object in a custom EventArgs. The listener object could then compare the Sender to itself and disregard any notifications which it initiated.

I think that this will work, but is there a better way? It will be a shame to lose properties. It seems very obvious to me that the initiator of a change does not need to be notified that it initiated it!

I have searched this extensively, and asked the question previously in a different way. I haven’t found anything so far which is related to this. Someone did mention StackTrace, which I’ll try but am concerned whether it will work with multiple threads.

Comment: Can you check in the property setter? If the value is same, don't do anything and return.

Comment: Thanks. If the setter checks it, it will still be fired the first time the property is changed. So the network manager class receives an external network alert, changes the property, which notifies the network manager it has changed, which it (say) updates a database over the network. Comparing in the setter does prevent it being endless (thank you) but still wastes the first change, which causes lots of extra unnecessary work, especially for externally facing interfaces.

Comment: @AmateurD  Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Right, but you need to stop the execution somewhere. And for that you would need to check on the property setters. Not sure if you are using threads, maybe try putting locks to synchronize your execution. A reproducible example would help more in understanding your issue.

Comment: Sounds like a design flaw. You should make the Network Manager class not to change/ set the exact same property again. Or use different setter so it does not trigger change/ event back to Network manager.

Comment: So one way would be to maintain an array of every change you make, and when the notification comes back, remove that change from the array and disregard it? I can’t see how the setter would know which class set the value. I suppose you could have a collection of every property x number of listener classes e.g. network_propertyA but it’s a lot of work to add another listener class in the future, thank you

Comment: You don't need to keep a track of every change. Even if you setter is being called at multiple places. Making sure that the same value does not get applied again and again and you don't call OnPropertyChanged if the value is same will stop the loop.

Comment: Thanks, but the setter will only prevent this the second time it is changed. E.g. network triggers MyObject sets property Name to “Joshua”, object setter notifies the network manager, which unnecessarily sends its own change back down the network. The network manager doesn’t know what changes it made without a list of them.

Comment: Then I guess you need to keep a sorted list of last submitted values. Or a simpler way would be to use a bool. Set the bool when the Network Triggers something. Wait for the loop to return to the Network, check for the bool. If the bool is set, reset it and return. This should take you out of the loop.

Comment: This sort of design where objects are mutually controlling and reacting to each other through property setters and multicast events is often flawed in my experience (other than in established UI patterns), and attempting to fix it within its own terms can quickly lead to massive complexity.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think I may have found an answer I can try. If I move the INotifyPropertyChanged from the setter to a separate method then I can include the Sender object in the method. It means each time the object is changed there is an extra method call but that is probably OK.